# Serializing output of a match result web scraper

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, web-scraping

[This is a follow up to a previous question.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/169075/scraping-current-day-counter-strike-match-results-from-a-website)

As part of learning the object oriented approach and web scraping in Python, I've set out to write a program that will give me match results of professional Counter-Strike games, in order that appears on [hltv.org](https://www.hltv.org/results). At first I just wanted a simple script that will download the website and get the results to print them out but I decided I don't have to stop there.

The program goes through the source code to find today's match results. Then, pieces of information like the winning team and their score are pulled out of that source code so they can be represented in certain ways.

I'd greatly appreciate feedback, so I can know what's good and what isn't about this code. If there is any improvements that could be implemented, I'd be eager to learn about them.

## Changes

First I'd like to thank user *alecxe* for his useful feedback and directing me on the right track.

#### Class

Most obvious change of all, from the code from the previous question, is that I have moved everything into a class. This is so I can eventually make this into a handy enough module.

#### `get_results`

The for loop, which pulls the pieces of information from the source code is now part of a `get_results` method.

In the first versions, I've completely omitted the possibility of a match ending in a tie. This can only happen if the match has a best-of-two format. The format is rather uncommon and it's usually adopted in group stages of smaller tournaments.

It came to me when I was trying to run the code and I got an unexpected `AttributeError`. It took me a while to realise the code wasn't suddenly broken; the tags in the source code simply change, from `team team-won` and `team`  to `team`  and `team` . As the for loop was looking for `team team-won` specifically, the search would return `None` and the error would raise.

I'm not really comfortable for catching that particular error, but for now it works the way I want it to. If anyone knows a better way, I'd appreciate some feedback on it.

#### OrderedDict & Serializing

To keep order of the games, I've implemented an OrderedDict, as regular dictionaries don't preserve the key order. Then, the `match_results` OrderedDict is dumped into JSON text. The data can be easily represented, as seen in the `print_results` method.

I'm not really sure if this is the most efficient way, I know it works just fine for this purpose. I haven't really done much with JSON text before.

## Code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import json
from collections import OrderedDict
from time import localtime, strftime

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


class ResultScraper:

    MAPS = {
        'mrg': 'Mirage',
        'trn': 'Train',
        'ovp': 'Overpass',
        'inf': 'Inferno',
        'cch': 'Cache',
        'cbl': 'Cobblestone',
        'nuke': 'Nuke',
        'bo2': 'Best-of-two',
        'bo3': 'Best-of-three',
        'bo5': 'Best-of-five',
        '-': 'Default win'
    }

    def __init__(self, stars=0):
        self.url = 'https://www.hltv.org/results'
        self.date = strftime('%d %B %Y')
        if isinstance(stars, int) and 1 <= stars <= 5:
            self.stars = stars
            self.url += '?stars={}'.format(self.stars)

    def scrape(self):
        source = requests.get(self.url).text
        return BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

    def check_match_dates(self, tag):
        result_tag = tag.name == 'div' and 'result-con' in tag.get('class', [])
        if not result_tag:
            return False

        timestamp = int(tag['data-zonedgrouping-entry-unix']) / 1000
        return strftime('%d %B %Y', localtime(timestamp)) == self.date

    def get_results(self):
        match_results = OrderedDict()
        soup = self.scrape()
        for result in soup(self.check_match_dates):
            timestamp = result['data-zonedgrouping-entry-unix']
            event = result.select_one('.event-name').get_text()
            map_played = result.select_one('.map-text').get_text()
            try:
                winning_team = result.select_one('.team.team-won').get_text()
                winning_team_score = result.select_one('.score-won').get_text()

                losing_team = result.select_one('.team.').get_text()
                losing_team_score = result.select_one('.score-lost').get_text()
            except AttributeError:
                winning_team = result.select_one('.team1').get_text(strip=True)
                losing_team = result.select_one('.team2').get_text(strip=True)

                winning_team_score = result.select_one('.score-tie').get_text()
                losing_team_score = winning_team_score

            match_results[timestamp] = {
                'winning_team': winning_team,
                'winning_team_score': winning_team_score,
                'losing_team': losing_team,
                'losing_team_score': losing_team_score,
                'event': event,
                'map': self.MAPS[map_played]
            }
        return json.dumps(match_results, indent=4, separators=(',', ':'))

    def print_results(self):
        results = json.loads(self.get_results(), object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
        if not results:
            print('No match results for {}'.format(self.date))
        else:
            for match in results.values():
                print('{winning_team:>20} {winning_team_score:<2} - '
                      '{losing_team_score:>2} {losing_team:<20}'
                      ' {map:<13}'.format(**match))
            print('\nCS:GO match results for {}'.format(self.date))
        print('Powered by HLTV.org')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rs = ResultScraper()
    rs.print_results()
```

Comment: This is a [follow-up question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/169075/scraping-current-day-counter-strike-match-results-from-a-website). Good work, btw. It looks great! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is really clean, great job!

> I'm not really comfortable for catching that particular error, but for now it works the way I want it to. If anyone knows a better way, I'd appreciate some feedback on it.

This is perfectly fine - it is even, generally speaking, much better than catching a broad `Exception` class. By catching a specific exception, you are not gonna miss a different exception if it is going to be raised in the future. More information at [Should I always specify an exception type in `except` statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14797375/should-i-always-specify-an-exception-type-in-except-statements.)

I would just probably add a clarifying comment in the exception handling logic explaining why we need it and what case does it handle.

Some minor points:

- you should probably throw a `ValueError` in case `stars` is not valid
- you can work on making the code more modular - extracting things like dealing with timestamps into separate "library" functions - beware of [God objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object) (it's not really an issue now, just something that may happen if the class is gonna grow this way)
- if performance matters, look into using faster third-party JSON libraries like `ujson` or `simplejson`
- improve on documentation - add documentation strings to your class methods
- the trailing dot inside the `.team.` CSS selector can be removed
- we can further improve performance by *parsing only the results list* with the help of a [`SoupStrainer` class](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parsing-only-part-of-a-document):

  ```
  parse_only = SoupStrainer(class_='results-all') 
  return BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml', parse_only=parse_only)
  ```

  Don't forget to import `SoupStrainer` from `bs4`.

Comment: No need to raise `ValueError` at all! Anything that isn't an `int` and outside of the specified range will just be ignored. Also, the leading dots are there to stay, removing them raises an `AttributeError` which isn't desirable. Using `SoupStrainer` did improve performance slightly though! Working on extracting functions and docstrings now. Thanks so much, appreciate your effort.

Comment: @LukaszSalitra oops, did I say leading? Sorry, meant trailing. Fixed. Thank you!